# Vagrant failing on Booting VM

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, ssd, vagrant

I recently re-installed Windows 7 64bit on an SSD. I then installed Virtual Box 4.3.16r95972 and vagrant Vagrant 1.6.5.

I went to https://vagrantcloud.com/ and got this box https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64

I did vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64. Everything went ok.

I then did vagrant up --debug.
I got a lot of stuff. This is the last part:

```
default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1) 
INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:\\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe", "modifyvm", "e3a7d92a-51f6-4cba-aff5-e7bbe8e
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 31999
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
INFO warden: Calling IN action:
INFO warden: Calling IN action:
INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe", "modifyvm", "e3a7d92a-51f6-4cba-aff5-e7bbe8e
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
INFO sanedefaults: Automatically figuring out whether to enable/disable NAT DNS proxy...
INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe", "modifyvm", "e3a7d92a-51f6-4cba-aff5-e7bbe8e
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
INFO warden: Calling IN action:
INFO interface: info: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
INFO interface: info: ==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations... INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe", "modifyvm", "e3a7d92a-51f6-4cba-aff5-e7bbe8e DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 0
INFO warden: Calling IN action:
INFO interface: info: Booting VM...
INFO interface: info: ==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Booting VM...
```

I get nothing more after the "Booting VM". I waited for more than 30m and nothing.
I hit ctrl+c and got this: (it's a lot so I used a paste site)

http://privatepaste.com/a166d9d290

but basically it gives me an error at:

```
Stderr:
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "e3a7d92a-51f6-4cba-aff5-e7bbe8eda9c9", "--type", "gui"]

Stderr:
 INFO interface: Machine: error-exit ["Vagrant::Errors::VBoxManageError", "There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant\nfor controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.\n\nCommand: [\"startvm\", \"e3a7d92a-51f6-4cba-aff5-e7bbe8eda9c9\", \"--type\", \"gui\"]\n\nStderr: "]
```

In the Vagrant file I did put vb.gui = true but I never saw any box, also in the VirtualBox manager window I never see the vm actually start.

I tried this website https://puphpet.com to generate a vagrant box (I have used this in the past and everything worked) but the results are the same as the above.

I tried looking for this bug and I did find similar issues but they were fixed when the user upgraded to VirtualBox 4.3.16 (which is the version I am currently using).

Anyone know how I can fix this? I need to work and I need a VM to work on.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Per this [post](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=63556), I've found that there are security issues with 4.3.16r95972.

So I upgraded to 4.3.17 r96342 and everything is working now.